# How do you train GANs using multiple GPUs with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

There are three main challenges: a) how do you [save and load the optimizer state](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10806), b) how do you use multiple GPU with nested models, see below, and c), how you create a workflow to optimize GPU and CPU utilization?

### Context

We have three components:

1. the discriminator
2. the generator, and
3. the GAN which has both the discriminator and the generator.

### Optimizer State

Since the discriminators are included in the GAN and they also need to be used separately during training - how do you save and load GANs? Now, I save the generators and discriminators separately and recompile the GAN for each training episode, but I lose the optimizer state this way.

### Multiple GPUs

This is what the API looks like:

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)
```

The challenge here is the same as with optimizers. Since the discriminator is included in GANs, you can't apply the `multi_gpu_model` to both the discriminator and the GAN. You can add a `multi_gpu_model` to both the discriminator and generator before you create the GAN, but from my experience it does not scale well and leads to poor GPU utilization.

### GPU and CPU utilization

The data can be preprocessed and queued using multiprocessing. Since the `multi_gpu_model` API does not support GANs, you need to frequently merge the weights and hop between CPUs and GPUs. Thus, I haven't found a clean way to utilize GPUs and CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

The multi_gpu_model can be used in each of the function for generator, discriminator and gan

```
def create_generator():
  #network architecture 
  generator = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
  generator = multi_gpu_model(generator, gpus=2)
  generator.compile()
  return generator
```

The same can be done for discriminator and gan.

Comment: That's a neat way to reuse the multi_gpu_model api, but it does not solve the problem of the optimizer state and cpu/gpu utilization.